# How do I properly stop new qthread after it receives signal from main thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread

I have 2 threads in my Qt app. Main thread and `myThread`. I want `myThread` to stop whenever it receives `workFinished` signal from corresponding `Worker` class OR when it receives `stopMyThread` signal from the main thread.

```cpp
void MyClass::myFunction()
{
    //DO SOME STUFF...
    myThread = new QThread(this); //myThread and myThreadWorker declarations are in .h file
    myThreadWorker = new Worker(this);
    if (!myThread->isRunning())
    {
        connect(myThread, &QThread::started, myThreadController, &Worker::doWork);

        connect(myThreadController, &Worker::workFinished, myThread, &QThread::quit);
        connect(this, &MyClass::stopMyThread, myThread, &QThread::quit);

        connect(myThreadController, &Worker::workFinished, myThreadController, &Worker::deleteLater);
        connect(this, &MyClass::stopMyThread, myThreadController, &Worker::deleteLater);

        connect(myThread, &QThread::finished, myThread, &QThread::deleteLater);

        myThreadWorker -> moveToThread(myThread);
        myThread -> start();
    }
}
```

Meanwhile in worker.h there is while loop which works like this:

```cpp
void Worker::doWork()
{
    while (buffer > 0)
    {
        buffer -= 5;
        //DO SOME STUFF
    }
    emit workFinished();
}
```

Is that a proper way to do this or does it causes some problems? My app crashes when `myThread` is stopped by signal from the main thread.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. If you asked how to fix your code, you'd have to extract a [mcve]. This will probably be difficult, since race conditions (which you probably have) are hard to isolate and reproduce, so using a debugger to investigate might be a better approach. That said, there are probably hundreds of questions asking how to stop a thread: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+%5Bqt%5D+stop+thread.

Comment: Note that in the code shown there's nothing to prevent `myFunction` being called while the `QThread` and `Worker` created by a previous call are still active.  I can certainly see that causing problems.  If not that then please provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the issue.